# OOP cpp base class and derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

```
Zoo::Zoo(const Zoo& other)//copy c'tor
{
    m_name = _strdup(other.m_name);
    m_address = _strdup(other.m_address);
    m_ticketPrice = other.m_ticketPrice;
    m_openHours = _strdup(other.m_openHours);
    m_closeHours = _strdup(other.m_closeHours);
    m_numOfAnimals = other.m_numOfAnimals;

     // Deep copy the animals array
    m_animals = new Animal * [other.m_numOfAnimals];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.m_numOfAnimals; i++)
    {
        m_animals[i] = new Animal(*other.m_animals[i]);
    }
}
```

hello, i have a problem with this copy c'tor... i dont wanna elevate the base class of the other.m_animals[i] but i have no idea how.

i rather would like to make it so it would save the derived class ( horse or flamingo ... )

Comment: What do you mean by "elevate"? If `Animal` is a base class then you may want to create a virtual `clone()` method and override it in the derived classes to ensure you create the correct type.

Comment: If this is not a school excercise to test pointers and memory management, please use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to do a deep copy of an array (or vector) of Animal*, but the contained animals may be of some derived type.  Is that correct?

If so, then you cannot use the Animal constructor because it won't construct the derived type.  As mentioned in a comment above, if you had:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual Animal* clone() = 0;  // or with an implementation if Animal is not abstract
};

class Horse : public Animal {
public:
   Horse* clone() override { return new Horse(*this); }
};

class Flamingo : public Animal {
public:
   Flamingo* clone() override { return new Flamingo(*this); }
};
```

(assuming your derived classes are copy-constructible).  You can have subclasses override a virtual function with a different return type as long as your return type is convertible to the return type in the base class.

Your initialization would then be:

```
m_animals = new Animal * [other.m_numOfAnimals];
for (int i = 0; i < other.m_numOfAnimals; i++)
{
    m_animals[i] = other.m_animals[i]->clone();
}
```

If m_animals were a std::vector<Animal*> instead of just a pointer, it would be:

```
std::transform( other.m_animals.begin(), other.m_animals.end(),
                std::back_inserter( m_animals ),
                []( Animal* a ){ return a->clone(); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use constructor delegation to call or initialize the base class constructor from the derived class.

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int);
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        B(int, int) : B(int, int, 'c');
        B(int, int, char) : A(int);
};
```